# Stochastic differential equation form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

A few days ago, I disccussed my Phd thesis (thesis defense), one of the mathematical mistakes that the committe members alerted me to it, is how to write correctley an ordinary differential equation or a stochastic differential equation, they said to me that the correct way to write an ordinary differential equation is:

$\frac{dx(t)}{dt}=f(x,t)$ and $dx(t)=f(x,t)dt$ is false, and for a stochastic differential equation the right way is $dx(t)=f(x,t)dt+LdB(t)$, $L$: is square root of the gain matrix of the process noise.

what is the rationale behind these two expression, because for example I saw in many times that the two expression are used for the deterministic models?

Comment: IMO, you should follow the committee members advice, but if you insist well in math everything is ok as long as you have defined your notation in a non ambiguous way, but this might hurt the notational habits of your reviewers I am not an academic though and this also might depend of the country you are defending your thesis.